# Setting up TLS communication between orderers and peers

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I've been putting together a Kubernetes setup for running a production Fabric 1.0.0 network, and the next step of that is adding TLS communication between all network resources.  In order to generate TLS certs, I've set up fabric-ca to run with multiple roots, the first CA being used to generate the MSP signing certs, and the second to generate the TLS artifacts.  I've also configured fabric-ca to generate TLS certs with a different profile, according to [this commit](https://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r/#/c/11103/11/cmd/fabric-ca-server/config.go).

The TLS certificates have a CN record matching the hostname of each server ("peer-x.peer"), and a number of SANs (but not the IP address of the server, since these are generated before those containers spin up).

TLS communication with fabric-ca-server/client seems to be working fine.  I can create enrollment certificates with both CAs for all of my peers and orderers.

When creating the orderer genesis block with `configtxgen`, I've taken the cacert from the TLS ca and placed that in the `tlscacerts` subdirectory of the org's msp directory, so it should be included where necessary.

I've been able to run the `peer channel create` and `peer channel join` commands successfully, but after the peers join the channel, I see this appear in the leader peer's log:

```
[deliveryClient] StartDeliverForChannel -> DEBU 307 This peer will pass blocks from orderer service to other peers for channel lynnhurst
[ConnProducer] NewConnection -> ERRO 308 Failed connecting to orderer-2.orderer:7050 , error: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
[ConnProducer] NewConnection -> ERRO 309 Failed connecting to orderer-1.orderer:7050 , error: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
[ConnProducer] NewConnection -> ERRO 30a Failed connecting to orderer-0.orderer:7050 , error: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
[deliveryClient] connect -> ERRO 30b Failed obtaining connection: Could not connect to any of the endpoints: [orderer-2.orderer:7050 orderer-1.orderer:7050 orderer-0.orderer:7050]`
```

And this is in the orderer log:

```
[grpc] Printf -> DEBU 418 grpc: Server.Serve failed to complete security handshake from "172.17.0.16:56444": EOF
```

Clearly, something still is not right about that TLS certificate, but would anyone have an idea as to what might need to change?  Do I need to include the IP addresses of the servers as SANs in the TLS CSRs?

Comment: Did you ensure that the TLS cert of the orderer is signed by cert of the TLS CA?

Comment: I believe so.  The TLS cert is coming from the second CA using `fabric-ca-client enroll ... --caname "TLSCA" --enrollment.profile tls` and referencing that keypair in the TLS config of the orderer.

Comment: Come to chat.hyperledger.org and I'll try to help you and then we can post the resolution here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this was a bug in Fabric 1.0.1 that would appear if your orderers and peers were in the same organization.

https://jira.hyperledger.org/browse/FAB-5845

Answer (score 1):

There are different configurations that you should make sure that you have done.

- You have to share the public key of each organization with the other menbers of your network.
- When you define the peers and orderers, you should define a specific configuration for the docker network. By default, docker containers cannot connect to containers that are in other hosts. So, for each container of your network you should define:

  > network_mode: host
- Finally, each node should resolve the host of the other nodes (I understand that you have done it)

Could you try it?! If you don't understand my answer or you requiere for more information, ask again, ok?! I hope that's useful.